# what does props in export default do?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-modules

Hi I am now learning React, and I saw this piece of code

```
import React from "react";
import {Component} from "react";

import {BackstageTheme} from '@backstage/theme'


const useStyles = makeStyles<BackstageTheme>(() =>
    createStyles({
        someStyle: {
            position: 'relative',
        }
    }),
);

class MyComponent extends Component<any, any> {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }


    componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
        this.fetchData(props.filters);
    }

    public componentDidMount() {

        this.fetchData(null);
    }

    public fetchData(filters) {
        // fetch data thru API
    }


    public render() {
       
        const classes = this.props.classes;
        return (
            //layout..


        );
    }
}

export default (props) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <MyComponent classes={classes} filters={props.filters}/>
    )
}
```

I am confused, at the bottom, export default,,

why pass a **props**, and why have **filters={props.filters}** ?

can I remove **filters={props.filters}** ?

can I just have
**export default MyComponent** ?

If this still works with **export default MyComponent** , make any difference to pass a props in???

Comment: The default export is an arrow function. In React, that is a _functional component_

Comment: Yes, you can export default a class, or a functional component like this. Either works

Answer (score 3):

Admittedly not having a name of function is confusing.

```
export default (props) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <MyComponent classes={classes} filters={props.filters}/>
    )
}
```

It's just a short cut. When this method is imported it can be named anything
Like

```
import MyComponentWrapper from './Filename'
```

It would be more understandable as

```
const MyComponentWrapper (props) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <MyComponent classes={classes} filters={props.filters}/>
    )
}
export default MyComponentWrapper
```

But importing it can be named anything, like

```
import SomeOtherName from './MyFile'
```

Hence the reason for the shortcut.

However, in vscode and other editors, autosuggestion works better if these components are named.

Answer (score 1):

The function which is exported at the bottom of your code is simply another Function Component and every React [Funciton Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) must receive as parameter `props` which is an object containing all attribute pass to the component.

Here is an example related to `props` consider you have a `HelloWord` component define like this

```
function (props) {
    return <p>Hello World</>
}
```

When you use this component in JSX like this

```
<HelloWorld name="John Doe"/>
```

The `props` argument pass to the function define above will be equal to `{"name": "John Doe", ...}` You can learn more about [Component and Props Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

Considering code which you have provide is in a file name `MyComponent.js` when you import this file without destructuring the export data from the file you get is the exported component. Learn more about [ES6 Module Default Export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#default_exports_versus_named_exports)

```
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';
```

This line will return exactly the functional component exported as default which is

```
export default (props) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <MyComponent classes={classes} filters={props.filters}/>
    )
}
```

Related to `props.filters` You can remove if but the `MyComponent` which you have define in your code expect to have a props name `filters` as you can see here

```
componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    this.fetchData(props.filters);
}
```

The Filter property is use to fetch some data in the [`componentWillReceiveProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) Life cycle method.

You can just  `export default MyComponent` but you will have to pass `classes` and `filters` props as they are use in the code of `MyComponent` and It will be exactly like here

```
return (
    <MyComponent classes={classes} filters={props.filters}/>
)
```